# how to format a string composed essentially of number separated by spaces in Java with Double.parseDouble

Tags: java

In this example, I'm waiting for a double 55000 but I'm getting a type error of NumberFormatException

```
 // After runing, this display a NumberFormatException
    System.err.println(Double.valueOf("55 000"));

    // After runing, this display a NumberFormatException
    System.err.println(Double.parseDouble("55 000"));
```

Comment: What number do you think `55 000` should yield? 55? 55,000? 55.000?

Comment: @G if i have a string "55 000", after formating, I should have 55000.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either to remove the white spaces before using `Double.parseDouble()`:

```
String input = "55 000";
double number = Double.parseDouble(input.replace(" ", ""));
System.out.println(number);
```

Or use `DecimalFormat` with a custom grouping separator to parse the String:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
double number = decimalFormat.parse(input).doubleValue();
System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the space, just iterate over the string and if the character is a space don't put it in a new String, then convert it to a double.

```
String dbl = "55 000";
String newDbl = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dbl.length(); i++){
    if (dbl.charAt(i) != ' '){
        newDbl+=dbl.charAt(i)
    }
}
double dub = Double.valueOf(newDbl);
```

This would give `55_000`, this is my interpretation of what you are trying to do. If you want 55.000 and can guarantee that the string will have a space

```
String dbl = "55 000";
int index = dbl.indexOf(" ");
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(dbl);
build.deleteCharAt(index);
build.insert(index,".");
double dub = Double.valueOf(build.toString());
```

`dub` would be `55.0`

Comment: I thought of this solution, but it is not effective for me. If each time I have to go through the string first before formatting it